# Is it possible to use a dedicated parity drive without striping?

Tags: ssd, raid, trim

I'm setting up a log server. I'd like to set them up so that each disk is independent of the next, but the last disk is parity of all the rest. The reason why I want this is because:

1. You can't enable TRIM with striping (as far as I know).
2. SSDs have a higher probability of corrupting data (thus the parity drive would be nice).

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [snapraid.](http://snapraid.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Snapraid does look pretty close to ideal. Will it really be a problem that my log server won't have more than several hundred gigabytes to it? I read this, and it made me a little worried: http://snapraid.sourceforge.net/faq.html#bakhome

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: psusi: You're losing your touch; you're ending up in the low-quality queue!  ;-)  @A.B. when reviewing low-quality answers, look at the user itself too.  21100 rep and just providing a link, means that that's the answer...

Comment: Indeed, the answer is simply you are looking for a program called snapraid.  The link to download said program is provided as a convenience.